# How can I combine min and max validation errors in React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

```
 

 <input
            {...register("subject", {
              maxLength: 50,
              minLength: 2,
              required: true,
            })}
            disabled={isLoading}
            id="subject"
            autoComplete="on"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Subject"
            className={`w-full ${errors.subject ? "outline-error" : ""}`}
          />
          {errors.subject?.type === "maxLength" && (
            <p className="text-error" role="alert">
              maxLength 50 characters
            </p>
          )}
          {errors.subject?.type === "minLength" && (
            <p className="text-error" role="alert">
              minLength 2
            </p>
          )}
          {errors.subject?.type === "required" && (
            <p className="text-error" role="alert">
              Subject is required
            </p>
          )}
```

I want the min and max errors to be combined... when I try to combine it doesn't work as I wanted. It sometimes show both error or or does't show error . I want when user empty the field the required error should show and when user enter something in the field if it does not match the min and max length the min max error show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going very long in this like you are making different different span for each and every requirement.
Instead of that you can do like this.

First take ***formState: { errors }*** attribute from useForm() in react-hook-form like this,

```
const { register, handleSubmit, reset, setValue, formState: { errors }, clearErrors } = useForm();
```

also import ErrorMessage Component from React-hook-form like this,

```
import { ErrorMessage } from "@hookform/error-message";
```

Then you can apply ErrorMessage component after input whenever you want like this...

```
<input type="text" className="form-control" 
    {...register("subject", {required : "* Enter subject ", 
                minLength:{
                value:2,
                message: "Minimum 2 Characters required"
                }, 
                maxLength: {
                value:50,
                message: "Max 50 is allowed"
                }
                } )}  />
  <ErrorMessage errors={errors} name="subject" 
                render={({message}) => (
          <span className="errorMessage" >{message}</span>
        )}
     />
```

Here you can give any custom message you want, and after you can de-structure in ErrorMessage component.
Thank you...!

Comment: this is great but i need to install separate library for this.. why didn't reack-hook-form make  something like this ...thanks for the help